# Does Matlab 2013a support retina display?

Tags: matlab, retina-display

The Matlab proposal in Area 51 was closed as duplicate of "Stack Overflow", so I assume this is the appropriate place for this question.

Does the 2013a version of Matlab support retina display?  I have 2012b and the plots and figures and pixelated looking.

Comment: Im pretty sure that all versions of matlab can be viewed using a retina display. When it comes to simple plots this is just a case of `garbage in? garbage out!` The plots are not rendered to be pretty and the display will not change that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about [retina displays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display) (I think that's a Mac OS thing, I'm on Windows), but MATLAB plots are not anti-aliased.

At least thats the case in the current version, [it seems](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update/) MATLAB is working on updating its graphics system to be AA by default.

[image: hg1]
[image: hg2]

There is an undocumented way to get [smooth lines](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-linesmoothing-property/) you can also play with.

Finally there are other tricks to get nice [smooth plots](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/29/smooth-matlab-graphics/) (by drawing at a higher resolution, then subsampling and saving the image). Take a look at this FEX submission: [myaa](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20979-myaa-my-anti-alias-for-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine in 2013a but in 2013b it looks blurry. The reason is that the in versions before 2013b Matlab used the native mac java engine but since apple is abandoning this, mathworks is forced to use another java engine.

See here: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-N0GH8T/